# List of users and the app version in Amplitude tool

Tags: ios, analytics, fastlane, mobile-analytics, amplitude-analytics

I need to find a list of all user using my iOS app and also the version they are on.

Currently, we are using amplitude for analytics.

Is there any ways I can get the list using amplitude.

If not can it be done using fastlane pilot?

Answer (score 2):

OK.  This you can definitely do in Amplitude.

[Amplitude screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RU2Z8.png)

This simple report will dump out a csv file containing a huge amount of data about your iOS users - including the app. version.

Hope this helps!